# Angular2, ng2-chart child rendering before parent

Tags: typescript, angular, ng2-charts

I am currently working on a visualization application with `Angular2` and `TypeScript` for the `frontend` and Spring-Boot for the `backend`. Now I am at the point where the data coming from the `backend` hast to be displayed in my ng2-chart components.

I am loading the data in my parent components ngOnInit() function. The data is pushed to two arrays which work as input for my child component like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._sqlService.getCubeErrors().subscribe(
      data => {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          this.barLabels.push(data[i]["monthCube"]);
          this.barData[0]["data"].push(data[i]["errors"]);
        }
      },
      err => { this.error = true }
    )
  }
```

and here my service:

```
getCubeErrors() {
    return this.http.get('/rest/cubeerrors').map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
```

The two arrays `barLabels` and `barData` are passed on to the child component like this:

```
<bar-chart [barLabels]="barLabels" [barData]="barData" ></bar-chart>
```

In my child component i am using them to create a chart:

```
    @Input() barData: any[];
    @Input() barLabels: Array<string>;

    public barChartData: any[] = this.barData;
    public barChartLabels: string[] = this.barLabels;
```

I tried to track the data with some console.log() breakpoints and it seems that they are the same.

The problem I am facing is, that somehow the chart of the child component is rendered before the `ngOnInit()` takes place and so my data is not displayed.
I was searching for a update function of some sort but wasn't successful.

I hope someone might have an answer for this,

Sebastian

Comment: ngOnChange would be called when impl of a conp changes but for that to function reference of array has to be changed. It won't detect pushing element in an array

Comment: I tried ngOnChanges() in my chart component for test purposes and it got fired so i think it did detect the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Arpit is correct - you should use `ngOnChanges` instead of `ngOnInit` for anything that relies on the data being passed to it through it's `@Input`s.

So your child component would be very similar, just it would have an `ngOnChanges` function which checks that the `@Input`s have been fetched before trying to use them.

```
@Input() barData: any[];
@Input() barLabels: Array<string>;

public barChartData: any[];
public barChartLabels: string[];

ngOnChanges(){
    if(this.barData && this.barLabels){
        this.barChartData = this.barData;
        this.barChartLabels = this.barLabels;

        //Do anything else that relies on these arrays being defined.
    }
}
```

[Here is the documentation.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#onchanges)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ngOnChange` to update the data for chart component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you give me an example how ngOnChange works?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out now, i missed the `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,` implementation in my child component.

Thanks for all the answers!